# how to get a variable by name by passing part of the variable name in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm trying to create a function that I'll use repeatedly to get an object by name, passing part of the object name into the function.

I tried this using the below snippet, and it is outputting `undefined`.

How can I get the actual variable by passing part of its name into the function like this?

```js
function writeObject(name){
   console.log(placeObjects[name+'Item']);
}

function placeObjects(){
  var availableObjects = new Array();

  availableObjects.push(new Object('image','kepler'));
  availableObjects.push(new Object('image','lightning'));
  availableObjects.push(new Object('image','tomato'));
  availableObjects.push(new Object('image','us'));
  
    var topItem = availableObjects[0];
    var leftItem = availableObjects[1];
    var bottomItem = availableObjects[2];
    var rightItem = availableObjects[3];

    writeObject('top');
    writeObject('left');
}

placeObjects();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @fubar thanks, but how would I refer to the variables in their current scope using the name dynamically as I am trying to do?

Comment: General idea of using variable access by concating it's name parts is bad. Imagine you will use code minify,  all of your var occurrences will change the name and logic will become incorrect. I would recommend using names as keys of some object.

Comment: @SerejaNagin okay, well how might I reference the variable by passing its entire name rather than concatenating it? Or can you give an example of what you suggest using names as keys of an object? I think my problem may have to do with locating the variable's parent.

Comment: @mike-eng Lets let A= {}; You can add property like a key/value: A['keyname'] = 'value'. Then to access it you can do A['keyname'] or A.keyname call. The only need is to have variable A in valid scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var placeObject={};
function writeObject(name){
   console.log(placeObject[name+'Item']);
}

function placeObjects(){
  var availableObjects = new Array();

  availableObjects.push(new Object('image','kepler'));
  availableObjects.push(new Object('image','lightning'));
  availableObjects.push(new Object('image','tomato'));
  availableObjects.push(new Object('image','us'));
  placeObject={topItem:availableObjects[0],leftItem:availableObjects[1],bottomItem:availableObjects[2],rightItem:availableObjects[3]};
   // var topItem = availableObjects[0];
   // var leftItem = availableObjects[1];
   // var bottomItem = availableObjects[2];
   // var rightItem = availableObjects[3];

writeObject('top');
writeObject('left');
}

placeObjects();
```

this will work. Remember I have changed the variable name at the top.This will return required abject at writeObject call.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your new Object('image','kepler') will be hard to access as you are not defining a key : value pair. You could try using the code below with object literals assigned to one of your directions in an object to make things simpler.

```js
function PageObject(top, left, bottom, right) {
    this.top = top;
    this.left = left;
    this.bottom = bottom;
    this.right = right;
    this.writeObject = function(direction) {
      return this[direction];
    };
}

var pageObject = new PageObject({'image':'kepler'}, {'image':'lightning'}, {'image':'tomato'}, {'image':'tomato'});
console.log(pageObject.top);
```